# Protractor 2.0 is not waiting to sendKeys() . Promises issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I Just updated to protractor 2.0 and I found some issues in my project.

An `expect()` fails because given text is `''` it seems expect is done before `sendKeys()` is finished.

```
elem.clear().sendKeys('Message');
expect(elem.getAttribute('value')).toBe('Message');
```

The error I get is:

> Expected '' to be 'Message'.

That worked before updating to protractor 2.0, and I know that one of the [beaking changes is related with then() and promises](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes):

> To enable the update and remove confusion, this removes the
>   element().then function unless there is an action result. This
>   function is completely unnecessary, because it would always resolve to
>   itself, but the removal may cause breaking changes. In other words, an
>   ElementFinder is now no longer a promise until an action has been
>   called.

But in other tests of my project it works, I think that the problem might be related that I am doing that expect inside a loop. Here whole code

```
describe('message', function() {
    it('Should fill out visible message fields', function(){
          getDisplayedElements(element.all(by.model('message')))
         .then(function(displayedMessageInputs){
              _.each(displayedMessageInputs, function(elem){
                  elem.clear().sendKeys('Message');
                  expect(elem.getAttribute('value')).toBe('Message');
              });
         });
    });
});
```

If I use then() functions it works but... I don't like it!

```
elem.clear().sendKeys('Message')
.then(function(){
    return elem.getAttribute('value');
})
.then(function(inputValue){
    expect(inputValue).toBe('Message');
});
```

Comment: Any chance you see a difference in behavior between Chrome and Firefox here? (Does it fail in Chrome but work as expected in Firefox?)

Answer (score 1):

The second way you have shown it is the correct way to do this. Promises are used to clearly organize asynchronous callback behavior. The sendKeys asynchronous callback cannot be captured unless the Promise resolves before you expect. Also, it looks like it is actually returning a Promise, in which case it seems that it is wise to use what is provided by the function. If you don't prefer to use two thens, you can always just expect:

```
elem.clear().sendKeys('Message')
.then(function(){
    expect(elem.getAttribute('value')).toBe('Message');
});
```

Comment: Thanks your code works, but I have a strange behavior. 
1.'Message' is written.
2. expect is pass.
3. Input is clear().

3rd step is really weird. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand what issue your facing now. I suspect that perhaps you need to set up (depending on what test framework you're using) a "done" functionality after the promise has resolved. In mocha, this is a function passed to the "it" that can be called once the promise has resolved. In jasmine, you can set up a runs/waitsFor/runs style async behavior test. You also most likely need to remove the element which you are modifying in an afterEach block unless you are not concerned with element mutations in between tests; something about which I would be concerned.

Comment: @BTC Protractor and webdriver implement some magic to chain promises, so both forms in the original question should work equivalently.  In protractor.  (See https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md)